# Performance of Panel vs User Control in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, performance

In a lot of online UI design Youtube tutorials, I often see them using a panel control as a rectangle (no children). I am wondering whether it would improve performance by just creating a new blank user control and using that as a rectangle.

I'm guessing the simple answer is:

> "There is no noticeable difference, might as well just use a panel"

but if there is a slight chance that I could boost performance by a tiny bit, I will take it.

Edit: Sorry for not clarifying, with an empty panel you would simply set it's background color, and same with the user control, creating a single rectange.

Comment: _boost performance_  - LOL. A 'simpler' control might be a Label but a performance 'boost' is not possible at this level. In fact before _boosting_ performance you would need to identify a performance _issue_.

Comment: *using a panel control as a rectangle*? What does it mean? Do you mean a surface for drawing or a Container to host other Controls? To *boost* the performance of what?

Comment: Probably just as a 'thing with a border', right?

Comment: No difference.  This only ever matters when you have many *dozens* of them.  At which point you use neither and use the form's Paint event to call Graphics.FillRectangle().

Comment: As far as windows is concerned an empty panel is doing the same as an empty user control. they are just both controls, they get rendered the same. Anyway this question is futile and likely an XY problem, meaning that your actual problem is likely something else that we dont know about, or what you are trying to do that needs to be rethought

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's think about the two approaches. On the one hand, we would have a panel control, which has some logic running under the hood. On the other hand we have a user control, which (probably) has a thinner logic under the hood. This is why you may think that your user control might perform better.

However, in order to properly found your hypothesis, you should

- aim to understand what happens under the hood (probably not an option, unfortunately)
- do some stress tests (this is an option, however)

You should imagine some situation which might actually happen, like having many such panels or user controls on your UI. Let's exagerate it. Let's implement a UI where you add thousands of panels and another one where you add thousands of user controls. You can compare:

- the time needed to draw the UI
- the time needed to repeatedly repaint the UI, maybe 100 times
- memory usage
- event handling
- multithreading

So, you can find out the answer to your question by referring to the evidence of reality. But it is important to clarify that this only has theoretic importance at this point, because in practice, if practical performance issue happens due to this reason, the problem will likely be different from the one that you anticipate when implementing your stress tests.